# How do I list the users who own files in a directory and the number of files and directories for each?

Tags: files, users, ls, command

Am new to Linux and would like to know how to list every user which owns a file in a given directory as well as how many files and directories they own.
I tried by using

```bsh
ls -l | cut -d" " -f3
```

but this list only user who owns the files/directory.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of the users who own files in a given directory:

```
stat -c %U /path/to/directory/* | sort -u
```

To find how many files and directories they own inside:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -maxdepth 1 ! -type l -user <username> | awk 'END{print "username owns " NR " files"}'
```